# Allow End Users to select which columns are visible using JS datatable

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

The table table is being rendered by django admin. I will not know the amount of columns, column names or row contents. What I will know is the table id `result_list`.

The issue is users want tables that can sometimes have 10+ columns. I want to provide a better user experience by either allowing users to select which columns to hide/show after the table has been rendered. My thoughts where to use Datatables but having a hard time finding the correct config.

Because this code snippet will be used by the default template, the code must be agnostic to the data inside the table.

Here is a snippet that I have:

```
$('#result_list').dataTable({
// initializers here
});
```

Typical generated table looks like:

```
<table id="result_list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already checked this datatable API that can toggle columns?
[Show and Hide DATATABLE](https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html)

I suggest dynamically `forEach` the `thead` column since it can't be static.
then use the link for your reference.

Comment: I initially thought about this solution and I did visit their documentation. I thought there maybe have been another solution. Iterating through elements  may lead to weird affects especially if there are changes. The table is generated by a third party library. I'll set this as the answer unless a better/cleaner solution is provided where I don't need to parse the thead.

Comment: or you can add filters first before rendering or calling your `result_list`, like by selecting the column they only want to see.

Comment: Answers should be self-contained, instead of [relying on external links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/671985), which may not always be available for all users. You can use links to [supplement your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing), of course.